# How to prevent a block from being cached?

Tags: 8, blocks

After login. I'm adding one sidebar block. Once I clear cache then only updates variable or it's value.

```
namespace Drupal\test_demo\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;

/**
 * Provides 'Sidebar' Block
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "sidebar_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Sidebar Block"),
 *   category = @Translation("Sidebar Block"),
 * )
 */

class SidebarBlock extends BlockBase {
  public function build() {
    return [
      '#markup' => $this->t('Sidebar'),
      '#cache' => [
            'max-age' => 0,
          ]
      ];
  }
}
```

In **mytheme.theme**

```
function theme_preprocess_block(array &$variables) {
  echo $variables['elements']['#id'];
}
```

How can I stop that block to being cached. So once I refresh the page. It loads the value immediately.

Comment: Your build method code looks fine. Did you clear the cache? I see your block does not have an ID on the code you posted above. Did you leave that part out? or did you not declare an ID for your block?

Comment: Hi @NoSssweat update code. Yes checked still issue

Comment: Try switching to the default Drupal theme Bartik and see if the issue persists there. Also, since you're using PHP 7 syntax, I assume your server is running on PHP 7, right?

Comment: Using PHP 7 correct

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Got the solution via https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/disable-block-caching-drupal-8

Add below function to your block

https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/disable-block-caching-drupal-8

```
public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
}
```

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-max-age

Comment: Nice find, altho I am convinced your original method should've worked, don't have time to test right now.

Comment: Yes @NoSssweat Yes it works fine now :)

Comment: @NoSssweat This is the solution that works for me too, I don't know if the '#cache' was removed from the render arrays.

Comment: This still work, and is so far the purest method

Comment: Is this working on drupal9 too?

Comment: It's worth to note that this only works when "Internal Page Cache" module is not installed (c.f. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/305832/custom-block-is-still-caching-for-anonymous-users-despite-getcachemaxage-being)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply switch Caching to None on advanced options of view's block

Comment: Nobody ever mentioned Views.