# Disable caching on a custom plugin block

Tags: 8, blocks, caching

I read a lot of posts on how to disable caching on a custom block but none seemed to give the perfect solution.

1. `$build['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0]` or `public function getCacheMaxAge() { return 0; }`: Do not seem to work, or at least for authenticated users
2. `\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger()`: Kill the complete page cache, not only the block ones
3. Lazy builders: Seems to work only for anonymous users

In my case, I have a block which renders a random node and it's clearly an issue while I'm not able to refresh this cache.

So how to set up such a block? (Drupal 8.4.3)

Posts giving not working solutions:

- [How to prevent a block from being cached?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252033/how-to-prevent-a-block-from-being-cached)
- [How do I correctly setup caching for my custom block showing content depending on the current node?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199527/how-do-i-correctly-setup-caching-for-my-custom-block-showing-content-depending-o)

---

Edit:

```
public function build() {
    [...]
    if ($prev_node) {
      $render_controller = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getViewBuilder($prev_node->getEntityTypeId());
      $build = $render_controller->view($prev_node, 'pagination');
      $build['#node']->field_custom = 'something';
    }
    return $build;
}

public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
}
```

Thank's to @Clive, it seems my issue is not linked to the block cache itself, but to the entity I render in this block. If so, I have no ideas how on to resolve this issue.

**After many searches, D7 `cache_clear_all('field:node:10', 'my_field')` function seems to do what I want to do. What is its equivalent for D8 ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a block from being cached?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252033/how-to-prevent-a-block-from-being-cached)

Comment: I know it is a duplicate, the fact is this post does not provide a solution for this particular issue. I've been asked in another post to create a new one to provide one with, I hope, a final solution.

Comment: Yes, that's why I want to disable caching for this specific block only. I have also a prev / next pagination block who loads the string "Previous" or "Next", and those strings are cached, so, on the next page, the "next" button become "previous". So, I really need to implement this for 2 blocks.

Comment: What you've done with the max-age is correct: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/cache-api/cache-max-age it might be your browser just caching the page and thats why it appears to be cached by drupal still. Try with the inspector tools open and caching disabled

Comment: @LeighMason I had a huge doubt on your suggestion but I gave it a try, and it does not work. The only way to view my block correctly is to flush Drupal cache.

Comment: Can you post your entire block code? The answer to the link I provided should've worked.

Comment: @Pauloscorps The duplicate definitely works for authenticated users, I just tried it in a vanilla Drupal install. That's internal and dynamic page cache turned on, browser cache disabled, logged in as user 1. When I add a `getCacheMaxAge` to a simple block outputting `time()` returning 0, the time changes every page load. When I remove that line, it's cached. The problem must be something specific to your environment/config

Comment: @No Sssweat I share my code in the edit section of my post. I'm logged in as super admin for my tests.

Comment: @Clive You're right, I tested a rendering with time() function and it works. Don't you think my issue could be caused by the fact I'm altering a node field? If so, how can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution, thanks to MXH on the Drupal Slack.
I had to clear the render array cache like this:

```
$render_controller = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getViewBuilder($node->getEntityTypeId());
$items['next'] = $render_controller->view($node, 'pagination');
$items['next']['#cache'] = ['disabled' => TRUE];
$items['next']['#node']->my_field = t('some text');
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue that you, here is what it worked for me.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK() for block.html.twig.
 */
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $blocks_to_cache = [
    'SOME_block',
  ];
  if (in_array($variables['base_plugin_id'], $blocks_to_cache)) {
    $variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
  }

}
```

So, In my my_module.module I search if I'm displaying this block, then I clean the cache for that block. You can several block names.

Comment: Thank you Carlos, but sadly, I tested it and it does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution here - https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/disable-block-caching-drupal-8

Add the below code to your block code file

public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
}

Comment: Had quite some time figuring out block caching in drupal 8, so I created this video (16 min.): Block caching explained https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaQa4q8omQw&