# Get argument from current URL in twig to generate a link with that argument

Tags: 8, theming, uri

I'm trying to get an argument from search page URL so that I can pass that argument to a link.
For example I have this URL for a search results page:
`http://domain.com/site-search?search_api_fulltext=foo`
And on that page I want to have a link that goes to:
`http://domain.com/other-search?search_api_fulltext=foo`

I've tried `{{ url('<current>') }}` but that only returns the domain and path, but not the arguments. I've been trying stuff like `{{ app.request.requestUri }}` but that returns nothing.

FWIW, I'm trying to include these links in a custom block that appears on the search results page.

Comment: app. is for symfony apps. You could preprocess this variable and pass it in.

Comment: I'm trying that with:
```function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $variables['current_path'] = $current_path;
}```
But its still not returning the arguments, just the page path.

Comment: Ah, I figured out the function:
```function rcorpta_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
  $variables['current_path'] = $current_path;
}```

Answer (score -1):

well if you are making a custom block then you are probably doing something like this ....

```
 $build = [];
 $build['#theme'] = 'your_template',
 return $build;
```

and then in you hook_theme().

```
 hook_theme() {
  return [
   'your_template' => [
     'render element' => 'children',
     'template' = 'your-templante-name',
    ],
  ];
 }
```

you don't need to pre prossess the block at all just make sure the block is not being cached aka add this to your block plugin.

see [How to prevent a block from being cached?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252033/how-to-prevent-a-block-from-being-cached)

```
public function getCacheMaxAge() {
  return 0;
}
```

then in your block function :

```
 $search_query = \Drupal::request()->get('search_api_fulltext');
 $build = [];
 $build['#theme'] = 'your_template',
 $build['#search_query'] =  $search_query,
 return $build;
....


 hook_theme() {
  return [
   'your_template' => [
     'render element' => 'children',
     'template' = 'your-templante-name',
     'variables' => [
       'search_query' => NULL,
     ],
    ],
  ];
 }
```

then in your twig template

```
{% if search_query %}
  do what you want here {{search_query}}
{% endif%}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try this later on. I did figure out how to do it in a way I'm not happy about where I used in my theme file:
```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
  $variables['current_path'] = $current_path;
}
```

And then in my twig:
```{% set search_string = current_path|split('=')|last %}```

But I want to come back and try your suggestion as I want everything in the custom module and not part of the theme.